# Error Web App Angular 2 IE 11 and Edge Error

Tags: angular

i have developer Angular 2 website. The web app works very well on chrome and Firefox, but on Edge and IE 11 in signup page, I receive this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'lang' of undefined or null reference
>   ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of null
>       at SignupComponent.push../src/components/farmowner/signup/signup.component.ts.SignupComponent.signup (signup.component.ts:71)

this is my signup component ts

```
signup(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form);
    if (form.valid) {            
        const user = JSON.parse(this.auth.getToken());
        this.model.nation = user.lang;
        this.busy = this.http.setSignup(this.model).subscribe((response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.showSuccess(response.data.msg);
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }, 5000);
        }, (response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.showError(response.error[0].msg);
        });
    } else {
        if (form.value.password && form.value.password.length < 8) {
            this.showError('Password must have at least 8 characters');
        } else if (!form.value.termcondition) {
            this.showError('Read and accept the Privacy Policy');
        } else {
            this.showError('All fields are required');
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the html part:

```
<form class="form-signin form-mobile" (ngSubmit)="signup(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate align="center">
        <div class="form-group input-group width input-group-lg mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'FIRSTNAME' | translate}}*" aria-label="FirstName"
            name="firstname" required [(ngModel)]="model.firstname" #firstname="ngModel">
          <i class="icon-position material-icons">create</i>
```

i have set in my project polyfills.ts in this way:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/object';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


if (document['documentMode'] || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
}

 import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Any help on how to resolve this error? 
I have the same error on Safari.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Look at the stack trace from the error to determine the line of code that has the error. This should provide a clue as to what is `undefined`.

Comment: Try using the browser developers tools to perform a step by step debugging to find out what is `undefined`.

Comment: Hi Saleh and george, i have edit my post with verbose error and other code

Comment: Apparently the method `this.auth.getToken()` is returning `null`. How does it work?

Comment: My signup page require a selection language...and when open page the defulat language is english but is not take, if i select language works and error not show